# Using an Array to analyze input and utilizing it for a counter of array listing within the input in Python

Tags: python, arrays, counter

this time I got stuck on the second part. Thought'll it'll be easier but I ended up getting a bunch of syntax error. Here's the program:

```
def main():

    Characters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"\
                  , "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N"\
                  , "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V"\
                  , "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

    text = (input("Type Something:  ")).upper()
    text2 = text.partition("!")[0]

    print(text2) #Utilizing it to make sure program is cutting the string once it 
                        #reaches an exclamation point

    for i in range(len(text2)):
        print(i, text2[i])

    A = 0
    B = 0
    C = 0
    D = 0
    E = 0
    F = 0
    G = 0
    H = 0
    I = 0
    J = 0
    K = 0
    L = 0
    M = 0
    N = 0
    O = 0
    P = 0
    Q = 0
    R = 0
    S = 0
    T = 0
    U = 0
    V = 0
    W = 0
    X = 0
    Y = 0
    Z = 0
    other = 0

main()
```

I need help in apply the array into the counter. I was thinking:

```
for y in text2:
            if Characters["A"] in text2:
                A+=1
        print(y)
```

However I just have a bunch of errors afterwards. I had an earlier version, but if counted all the unit instead of a specific one. In my mind I get the feeling that I'm going to have to utilize the len function for the counter but I can't contemplate where. Can someone please explain the proper programming and the proper utilization of the len function in something like this. Thanks to whoever does help.

sorry for the confusing question

*TIGER!storm *

The program would read only: TIGER

Then what I'm trying to do is to write a code in which the program would count each letter in the input. So utilizing the array it should produce a count of: T=1, I=1, G=I, E=1, R=1 However writing the program for the counter is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: I can't even begin to understand what you want to do. You could start by showing an example of input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: Sorry about that. When a person types something lets say: TIGER!storm the program would read only TIGER. Then what I'm trying to do is to write a code in which the program would count each letter in the input. So utilizing the array it should produce a count of:         T=1, I=1, G=I, E=1, R=1 However writing the program for the counter is what I'm having trouble with. Again sorry for the confusing question.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* what you're trying to do is count how often each letter occurs in `text2`. If that's the case, there are a number of things wrong here.

First, stop saying array. These are *lists* that you're using. Arrays are not common in Python.

Second, you've written `if Characters["A"]`. This doesn't make any sense. Lists are indexed by integers. You'd have to say `if Characters[0]`. So, to fix your code you'd have to do something like

```
for c in text2
    if c == Characters[0]:
        A += 1
    if c == Characters[1]:
        B += 1
    ...
    if c == Characters[25]:
        Z += 1
```

**But this is completely the wrong way to do this.**

You should probably use a *dictionary*. There's also some useful attributes in the `string` module that will save you the trouble of writing out each character.

Something like this will be much easier.

```
import string

text = (input("Type Something:  ")).upper()
text2 = text.partition("!")[0]

chars = {}
for c in string.uppercase:
    chars[c] = 0

for c in text2:
    chars[c] += 1

print chars
```

There are even more compact ways of doing this sort of thing. But this should be relatively clear to you. Please don't write 26 `if` statements and have 26 variables.

Comment: Thank you so much that exactly what I was looking for. I'm surprise at how simple it was, I completely overcomplicated the coding. I'll see about utilizing the dictionary it would makes things much more easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always use Python `maps` for counting problems. So my solution would go something like:

```
frequences = {}
the_input = (input("Type Something:  ")).upper()
text = the_input.split('!')[0]

for char in text:
    # find char frequence in map or return 0
    frequences[char] = frequences.get(char, 0) + 1

print frequences
```